# Simple hello world program produces: ld: 1: Syntax error: ")" unexpected

Tags: c, gcc

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

When I want to compile this sample code with `gcc aa.c -o tt` I get an error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: 1: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
collect2: error: ld returned 2 exit status
```

I got this error when making a repo to install and I got the below error in the log file (a portion of the file).

```
gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-6ubuntu2) 
configure:3674: $? = 0
configure:3663: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3674: $? = 1
configure:3663: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3674: $? = 1
configure:3694: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3716: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
/usr/bin/ld: 1: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
collect2: error: ld returned 2 exit status
configure:3720: $? = 1
```

Comment: Looks like a broken toolchain installation.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/645808/cant-compile-any-c-c-program-linker-problem

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Your `/usr/bin/ld`  must have been messed with.

Comment: @4386427 there's no code they could possibly compile that should lead to `/usr/bin/ld` failing to execute, so I think that's unfair. It's a toolchain problem.

Comment: And to the OP - you need to know your specific OS and distribution to ask  a good question about fixing the toolchain, since it is specific to your package management system.

Comment: @Useless Perhaps but... why would `ld` give this syntax error ?

Comment: @4386427 Looks like it is being interpreted as a script

Comment: @EugeneSh. Not sure what you mean but... My guess is that OP made some simplifications while posting this question. These simplifications hides the real problem. But it is just a guess...

Comment: @4386427 I mean that `ld` here is expected to be script, not binary executable. And as a script it has a syntax error

Comment: Could be a problem with linker script used by the linker.  Try running "ld --verbose" to print it.

Comment: @dbdush result is ===> -bash: /usr/bin/ld: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Comment: `ls -l /usr/bin/ld` ?

Comment: @EugeneSh. result is =====>   /usr/bin/ld -> x86_64-linux-gnu-ld

Comment: And `ls -l /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld` and `file /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld`?

Comment: Do the same with `x86_64-linux-gnu-ld` . I mean follow the symlinks till you find the actual executable

Comment: "I got this error when making a repo to install ..." Seems to me that the C code is irrelevant here... instead something you didn't post is.

Comment: @dbush  result is =>  /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld -> x86_64-linux-gnu-ld.bfd

Comment: `ld` is the linker - to have got to the point of linking, the compilation was successful, so the code is not the issue - most likely nothing will link because your toolchain is screwed up somehow.

Comment: You may need to reinstall binutils and gcc.

Comment: I installed but  result same

Comment: What OS / distro / version are you on?  Also, did you keep tracing links until you found the actual file?  Is it a binary or a script?  If it's a script, what does it look like?

Comment: Just to make it clear: How exactly did you reinstall... the exact commands. After that... did you only issue the command: `gcc aa.c -o tt` ? And it failed with the same error? There is so much info missing here

Comment: @dbush my os => Ubuntu 7.5.0-6ubuntu2, that file was a binary

Comment: @4386427 I used these commands: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gcc-7 g++-7 ` and `sudo apt-get install --reinstall binutils`

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/187888/what-is-the-correct-way-to-completely-remove-an-application

Comment: @4386427 Now when I run `gcc aa.c -o tt` I got this error `collect2: fatal error: cannot find 'ld'`

Comment: And Now I Installed `sudo apt install --reinstall binutils` ,  and I returned to my main error

Comment: @FarshidShekari `Ubuntu 7.5.0-6ubuntu2` is part of the gcc version.  The OS version can be found in /etc/lsb_release.

Comment: hmm... I have no access to my ubuntu machine from here but maybe tomorrow I can check out a few things and get back to you.

Comment: @4386427 I'll be grateful